# Weird scope behavior

Tags: android

So i have this code in android (interface method implementation in the activity) The app runs perfectly well.

```
public void Clicks(int clickCounter) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    AnotherFragment another_fragment = (AnotherFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.another_fragment);
    another_fragment.showClicks(clickCounter);
}
```

Now, when i try to declare fragmentManager and another_fragment as class variables like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentInterface{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    AnotherFragment anotherFragment;

    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    anotherFragment = (AnotherFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.another_fragment);
    ...
}
```

it causes the app to crash. Why is it acting this way?

Comment: Please post your crash log.

Comment: You're trying to run code in a random place; that's not how Java works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
anotherFragment = (AnotherFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.another_fragment);
```

is not in any method block. You are trying to fetch those values before Activity is ready. Move this inside a method which is called after loading of `AnotherFragment`.

Comment: Yes, i did sort that out. But I'm wondering why must it be inside my interface method implementation?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be inside any method as long as `AnotherFragemnt` is loaded by that time.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you get a `NullPointerException`, right?

That's because you run your code before your `Activity` "is ready".

Your `Activtiy` is ready in `onCreate()`, for example. So put our code there.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentInterface {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    AnotherFragment anotherFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        anotherFragment = (AnotherFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.another_fragment);
   }
}
```

You can find out more about the Activity Lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle).